# How do we find the matrix for $T$ relative to $\{1,t,t^2\}$ for $\mathbb{P}_2$ and standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Define $T: \mathbb{P}_2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $T(\vec{p}) = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{p}(-1) \\ \vec{p}(0) \\ \vec{p}(1) \end{bmatrix}$.

> How do we find the matrix for $T$ relative to $\{1,t,t^2\}$ for $\mathbb{P}_2$ and standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know that the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. When the transformation is defined explicitly, i.e. $T(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=5a_2t$ for $T: \mathbb{P}_2 \to \mathbb{P}_2$ for instance, I know how to construct such a matrix, but i'm getting thrown off here by the values that the polynomial takes on, and I don't think we can know what kind of a polynomial $\vec{p}$ really is right? How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is to transform each basis vector for your domain (in this case $1, t, t^2$) and write the result as a coordinate vector in terms of the basis for your range ($e_1, e_2, e_3$). These coordinate vectors are the columns of the matrix.

For example,
$$T(1) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) = 1e_1 + 1e_2 + 1e_3.$$
Reading these coefficients, we get a coordinate vector of $(1, 1, 1)$ with respect to the standard basis (Surprise! Under the standard basis, the coordinate vector is always the same as the original vector). This implies that the first column of your matrix is given by:
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & \cdot & \cdot \\ 1 & \cdot & \cdot \\ 1 & \cdot & \cdot\end{matrix} \right).$$
Fill in the rest by similarly dealing with $T(t)$ and $T(t^2)$.